# Can we use maps for searching instead of binary search?

Tags: python, c++, algorithm, data-structures

Maps give O(1) look-up. Can't we go through the array once and build a map corresponding to its index (the opposite of array) and when we want to search something we can call `map[VALUE]` and it will return the index.

It might not work for large values in array but assuming `a[i]<10^5`, can't we do this instead of binary search? Then, each query will be O(1).

P.S: i did mean unordered map..

Comment: Yes, why do you think you can't?

Comment: "Maps give O(1) look-up" No. `std::map` is `O(log(n))`. `std::unordered_map` is `O(1)` on average.

Comment: Sure you can … But here's a question .. What if the value changes in the array? You'd have to update the map as well. What if there's more than one of the same value in the array? How would you handle that?

Comment: Don't forget that while `O(1)` may mean "constant time", that "time" might be huge. A `O(n)` algorithm can easily outperform a `O(1)` one if the latter has a 1 year constant overhead for each lookup while the former uses (1ms * `n`) per lookup. Algorithmic complexity is not the same as real life run time.

Comment: In database terminology, you are describing an *index table*.  All of your data is placed into a `std::vector`.  The index table is a `std::map<key, vector-index>`.  You can create multiple index tables, usually one per indexed field, and not have to sort the data in the `std::vector`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A [hash table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table), like a Python dictionary, will give amortized constant average cost per look up.

For large data sets this may become an interesting alternative to binary search.

Some algorithms may absolutely need a binary search for the following reason:

When the lookup value is not in the data set, a binary search can still tell what the least value is in the data set that is greater than the lookup value, and the greatest that is less, at the same *O(logn)* cost.

To me the matter of duplicates is less of an issue, as you could store tuples of (value, frequency) or (value, [payload1, payload2, ...]) in your array, and so still use a hash table.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the problems you might want to consider -

- You can't store multiple elements of the same value in map
- The lookup time is `O(log(n))` and not `O(1)`
- It's not magic that happens in map which allows us to access it in lesser time. There's an hashing process going on in the background in `unordered_map` which gives `O(1)`and that takes time as well. So, the big O hides a big constant time factor. Standard `map` gives you a `O(logn)` lookup, same time complexity as binary search in an array.

---

The **average time complexity** of searching you get is about the **same**. The main problem you will have using standard maps in C++ is that it won't be able to hold  multiple elements that have same values. One advantage that you might get using map is the deletion and insertion time will be `O(logn)`.

So, if you know that the dataset you will be working on **doesn't have duplicate elements** and/or there will be **frequent addition/deletion** of elements, then you can surely consider map as the better alternative in this case

Comment: Why would a map be hashing? An `unordered_map`, sure, but then it is `O(1)`

Comment: Typically the expense of hashing is comparable to the expense of comparing keys, so that constant factor is not likely to be big enough to dominate the search.

Comment: The main advantage of a map over binary search in an array is that you have O(log n) insertion and deletion as well as look up.

Comment: @Barmar True. But it will depend on size of data as well. Sometimes hashing maybe a lot more expensive than comparing keys as you mentioned(taking into account collision and all). I maybe wrong but that's what the idea I had till now

Comment: Unless the dataset is large, none of this makes much difference.

Comment: There are standard associative containers that allow duplicates like as [std::multimap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) and [std::unordered_multimap](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap)

Answer (score 0):

As the exact running time will depend on the length and type of the keys, their distribution, their number, it is advisable to benchmark for your particular application.